# I am receiving this error relating to Geofencing Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, geofencing

2023-07-06 11:29:29.787 28557-28595 SnapshotHandler         com.example.geofencing_testing_env   I  Unable to retrieve flag snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier#com.example.geofencing_testing_env, using defaults.
2023-07-06 11:29:29.799 28557-28596 MobStoreFlagStore       com.example.geofencing_testing_env   W  Unable to update local snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier#com.example.geofencing_testing_env, may result in stale flags.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.example.geofencing_testing_env, sha256=[56536ddbfefcc92cc30122262b633f84a43f891ab838ef9f5dff1ec8776f9d8d], atk=false, ver=232414047.true (go/gsrlt)
at m.ajx.s(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414047@23.24.14 (190800-0):3)
at m.ajx.get(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414047@23.24.14 (190800-0):2)
at m.alh.g(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414047@23.24.14 (190800-0):2)
at m.yz.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414047@23.24.14 (190800-0):1)
at m.zb.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414047@23.24.14 (190800-0):0)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:463)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: GoogleCertificatesRslt: not allowed: pkg=com.example.geofencing_testing_env, sha256=[56536ddbfefcc92cc30122262b633f84a43f891ab838ef9f5dff1ec8776f9d8d], atk=false, ver=232414047.true (go/gsrlt)
at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3011)
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2995)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2978)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2920)
at m.fe.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414047@23.24.14 (190800-0):2)
at m.ry.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414047@23.24.14 (190800-0):4)
at m.jl.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414047@23.24.14 (190800-0):2)
at m.kj.t(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414047@23.24.14 (190800-0):2)
at m.kj.u(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414047@23.24.14 (190800-0):3)
at m.kj.e(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414047@23.24.14 (190800-0):2)
at m.kn.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@232414047@23.24.14 (190800-0):78)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

From LogCat I am receiving that Error and the Map is crashing when launching the application on Android Studio Emulator. I have done numerous of troubleshooting steps trying to fix this.

1. Cleaning and Rebuilding the Project
2. Using Physical and Different Emulators
3. Updated all dependencies

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.